# Proof of The Projective Nullstellensatz

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am looking at the proof of the projective nulletellensatz given by Miles Reid in his book 'Undergraduate algebra'.

He makes the claim that for an algebraic closed field $K$ with homogeneous ideal $J$ of $K[X_1, \ldots, X_n]$, that, if $V_p(J) \neq \emptyset$ then $IV_p(J) =IV_a(J)$. I can reason as to why $IV_a(J) \subseteq IV_p(J)$. I cannot my reason as to why the reverse inclusion holds and to complete the proof. Can someone please illuminate me as to why?

Here $V_p$ represents the projective closure and $V_a$ the zarski closure.

Comment: Define both side of $IV_p(J) =IV_a(J)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that by $V_A(J)$ you mean all $x\in K^n$ such that $f(x)=0$ for all $f\in J$. Note that $V_P(J)$ is obtained from $V_A(J)$ by going modulo the usual equivalence relation identifying $(x_1,..,x_n)\sim (tx_1,..,tx_n)$ so if $f$ vanishes on all points of $V_A(J)$ it also vanishes on $V_P(J)$ so $I(V_A(J))$ is a subset of $I(V_P(J))$ now by definition $I(V_P(J))$ is the ideal generated by "homogeneous" polynomials which vanishes at all points on $V_P(J)$ and $I(V_A(J))$ by definition is the ideal generated by "all" polynomials which vanish at all points on $V_A(J)$ .So to conclude if a homogenous polynomial vanishes on a point in $V_P(J)$ so it vanishes at all points belonging to it's class (ie the pre image of a point under the above mentioned equivalence relation) so if $f$ vanishes at all points on $V_P(J)$ then it should vanish at all points of the pre image of $V_P(J)$ under the equivalence so $f\in I(V_A(J))$ so $I(V_P(J))$ is a subset of $I(V_A(J))$ $\implies I(V_P(J))=I(V_A(J))=\sqrt(J)$ .